# Is superwebsocket available in asp.net by default?

Tags: c#, websocket

Is [superwebsocket](http://superwebsocket.codeplex.com/)  available in ASP.NET by default?

If not how to configure it for mono.net environmen ? Is there a separate server side code running for superwebsocket ?

Comment: Are you talking about this: http://superwebsocket.codeplex.com/ ?

Comment: yes richard it the same one i am talking about

Comment: OK. I've cleaned up the A and added the trivial answer based on a short visit to the project's set. Hence -1.

Comment: Last comment: s/A/Q/ of course.

Answer (score 3):

It is not in ASP.NET by default, because it is not a project of Microsoft.

It can run on Mono 2.10 because SuperSocket(SuperWebSocket's underlying framework) has supported Mono 2.10. But you need to do two things:
1) Reference latest version of SuperSocket
2) Use Unix version log4net configuration file instead:
http://supersocket.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/65874#1405604

There is project called SuperWebSocketService in source code which allow you run SuperWebSocket as a console application or a windows service!

Comment: quite a few of your answers link to your SuperSocket project on CodePlex but you don't disclose in your answers or on your SO profile that you are the project coordinator. To quote from the SO FAQ [regarding promoting websites or products](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#promotion): *Post good, relevant answers, and if they happen to be about your product or website, so be it. However, you must disclose your affiliation in your answers.* (I suggest you read that whole paragraph). Please try to stay within these guidelines. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> Is superwebsocket available in ASP.NET by default?

No.

That's why the [Codeplex](http://codeplex.com) project exists.

> If not how to configure it for mono.net environmen ?

The project has a download but no documentation: either try yourself or ask a question on the project site (there are "Issue Tracker" and "Discussion" areas to use).

> Is there a separate server side code running for superwebsocket ?

As it adds functionality to ASP.NET the answer must be "Yes".