# Trying to get SuperWebSocket server working under mono/c#

Tags: c#, javascript, mono, websocket

I was using Nugget before (http://nugget.codeplex.com/), but when I upgraded to Chrome 14, it stopped working, and that's when I found this project: http://superwebsocket.codeplex.com/.

I've read this bit here: [Is superwebsocket available in asp.net by default?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5415589/is-superwebsocket-available-in-asp-net-by-default), and I've also built the mono version of SuperSocket. Connecting with Chrome 14, and the websocket just shows as pending in Chrome.

I see a message like this in the server side logfile:

INFO  2011-09-22 23:44:03,924 17166ms uer - WebSocket Server - Session: 1a2dc865-9d02-468e-ac7b-26f3d0b96a2a/127.0.0.1:49261
New SocketSession was accepted!

But the WebSocketServer.NewSessionConnected event never fires.  I do see the WebSocketServer.SessionClosed event firing however.

Anyone have any ideas why the new session connection event never fires, and/or why Chrome never receives any response from the socket server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which version of SuperWebSocket are you using?

The latest source support Chrome 14, but there is no drop for it for now.

So you should download source code by yourself.

Another problem is SuperSocket, SuperSocket 1.4 SP1 which SuperWebSocket base on has no MONO assemblies in  release package, so you need build it by yourself.

Comment: okay great! I am currently using mono 2.10, and I did build SuperSocket 1.4 SP1 (the mono version0, but I didn't download the source code from svn foor SuperWebSocket.  I'll try that today, and then write back with my findings. Thanks Kerry!

Comment: so... I'm using Mono 2.10.2, I've checked out SuperWebSocket from svn, built it against SuperSocket.Mono.sln 1.4 SP1, and still no dice. :(